# How to give Azure App permission to Azure SQL

Tags: .net, azure

I deployed a rest api in my azure that should be accessing my Azure SQL. I already registered my App in "App Registration" in Azure and with my Client ID and Client Secret I was able to get my client token. I have a question though, how will I give permission to my Client ID so that it can access my SQL.

I am reading few topics like this one

https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/configuring-aad-authentication-to-azure-sql-databases/

And with that they added the client ID in a Service Principal and the Service Principal was the one that was given permission.

But I am not sure if its possible to add my Client ID as a member of AAD(Azure Active Directory) Group instead of Service Principal? Because I noticed that you can also add permission to AAD Group inside a sql.

Note: Both my Azure and my Rest api is on the same Azure Tenant

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to add a service principal as Azure  AD group member. Then set the group as Azure SQL database user. Right? if so you can do that.

Comment: So its not possible to add App as a member of an AAD Group? So for app to have permission to SQL it only achieve that by add it to a Service Principle? I believe when you create an APP it should already be tied to a Service Principle right? 

I have not Azure Admin permission but I have to ask someone to check that for me.

Comment: If you create AD application via Azure portal,  the service principal and AD application will be created at the same time.

Comment: Hi Billy Any update?

Comment: Hi @JimXu thanks for checking up on this. I was able connect my web app to my sql through MSI instead. My client preferred giving permission through MSI rather than Service Principle.

Comment: When you enable Azure MSI, it will also create a service principal in Azure AD. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview